# QuickLook won't show scaled-down SVG preview

Tags: finder, quicklook

I have some SVG files, sketch drawings of a room. I've used real units in them as I want them to server as a reference. The SVG dimensions are something like 300 in by 200 in. QuickLook shows me a preview with tiny scroll bars, with the image at full scale. Is there a way to have Quicklook show a scaled-to-screen size version, by default?

In browser, I've been able to apply an overriding CSS style, width & height `100%`. Can I apply CSS to Quicklook previews?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out `qlmanage` supports pre- or batch [rendering thumbnails](https://alexwlchan.net/2020/using-qlmanage-to-create-thumbnails-on-macos/). You can specify output pixel dimension with `-s [num]`.

Verbosely named:

```
qlmanage -t -o thumbnails -s 1000 drawing.svg
```

Put thumbnail in current directory, as `[src].png`, here `drawing.svg.png`:

```
qlmanage -t -o . -s 1000 drawing.svg
```

To view, use `qlmanage -p [file]`.